# Invalid layout param in a LinearLayout: layout_column

Tags: android, android-layout, warnings

I'm getting this warning, the program still builds and runs properly. I just want to know how to get rid of it.

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/myimage4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        **android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="0"**
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`android:layout_column` and `android:layout_row` are only valid in Tabular layouts, and they don't exist in a LinearLayout. If you're using a LinearLayout, you don't need them, and can safely be removed.